# paypal android sdk customization

Tags: paypal

I need to integrate the Paypal library with my application i have a requirement like when ever the user is registering with the application then they can enter their paypal account information and check whether the user is exist or not. if the user exists register with the application after some steps ..........when ever the user click pay button redirects to the Paypal library payment processing .
I have some Queries

1. Paypal SDKs allows to customize the Library?
2. how to customize the User interface(pay pal library) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cannot ask PayPal whether a user exists, nor can you customize the SDK other than configuration available to you through extras (see [javadocs](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/)).